# ninject mvc and wcf

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions

Ninject has extentions for mvc and wcf but in our case mvc application is hosting wcf as well. How do u go about using both, looks like both extention provides base class for httpapplication(global.aspx),

**What is the correct way of using it?**

At this moment looks like i need to grab pieces out of wcf extention and put it in mvc extention to get both working.

Answer (score 0):

The extensions just provide shortcuts for functionality already in Ninject.  i.e., the MVC application registers it's own controller factory, something you can do manually.  Can you just do the WCF stuff manually in your application class?